# Inequalities involving x and y.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing, proof-verification

I am asked to prove:

$(x-y)^3 \ge x^3-3x^2y$ where $x,y$ are real and $0 < y < x$

I am told Bernoulli's inequality may help.

I have however reduced this to $3xy^2 - y^3 \ge 0$. I have simplified this to $3x \ge y$ and I am done, however I feel this may be an incorrect step? Is this proof correct?

Comment: Looks good. You're dividing by $y^2$ which is positive.

Comment: thanks @Macavity! Would it be simpler if I was to use Bernoulli inequality? I cannot see how it fits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to use Bernoulli Inequality, note
$$(x-y)^3 = x^3\left(1-\frac{y}{x} \right)^3 \ge x^3\left(1-3\frac{y}{x} \right) = x^3-3x^2y$$